# Face orientation

Tags: faces, normals

I got a relatively high poly model with faces that aren't in the right orientation. Is there any way to flip all wrong orientated faces but selecting them manually?

After question edit:

I turned down the polys now and merging didn't work either. The model is a letter and currently only a surface, but i want to put a solidify mod on it.  I subdivided the surface before for higher res, and now the polys look in the wrong direction which shows when applying the solidifier.
[image]

Comment: as Crantisz said - pls write all you have tried before so we don't waste our times with answers you already now. So click on "Edit" and improve your question

Comment: If recalculating normals outside doesn't work, you likely have duplicate or non-manifold faces. Try selecting all then press M (merge), and select "by distance". This will get rid of any dupes - you may or may not need to recalculate normals again afterwards. If that doesn't work, as others have mentioned, it would be helpful if you could post some specifics about your project, (ideally) along with some screenshots, so we can help you diagnose the problem better.

Answer (score 2):

Select all → <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> This will automatically recalculates normals outside.

Comment: I tried that already but it doesn't work...

Comment: How it supposed we should know that you have already tried this? Please, elaborate your question and add a screenshot of file, so we could understand why this doesn't work